# Execute inline sql to update a table using nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Sorry if this has been asked before, I did a search but couldn't find anything.

Is it possible to execute inline sql in nHibernate? I have something like this which I would like to run against the dB:

```
_session.CreateSQLQuery(
              @"update things
                set defaultThing = 0 where parentId = :parentId AND thingId <> :thingId")
                .SetInt32("parentId ", parent.Id)
                .SetInt32("thingId", thing.Id)
                ;
```

I suppose I could loop through a bunch of 'things' and set the defaultThing setting to false then call `_session.Update(thing)`, but if I can do it how I outlined above, that would be great.

Comment: Don't know about using SQL for this, but using HQL it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use `ExecuteUpdate()` on that query. It's the equivalent of `IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

As kay mentioned, you can use HQL too. Check [12.3. DML-style operations](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)

Comment: Good to know, but I would still use HQL in order to keep it DB neutral.

Comment: Of course I have read it. You wrote "you can use HQL". I would have recommended it, but nevermind :)

Comment: @kay.herzam yeah, I'd recommend it too :-)

Comment: hql and db neutral - that's awesome. diego and kay, thanks for the enlightenment, that's just what i needed!